# Service fabric client encryption

Tags: certificate, azure-service-fabric

Does the client x.509 certificate encrypt the data as well as handle authorization?

Documentation says it handles authorization and message signing. But does that mean the data is encrypted in transit?

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT encrypted when using Secure-Cluster with Certificates (Node2Node + Client2Node) with default Rpc-Endpoints. In Wireshark you can see the whole communication. It seems just for authorization.

Endpoints with https are encrypted of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a given x509 certificate will be used to encrypt the data while communication happens between a client and the cluster. As for authorization, it means that you could set what client certificates will posses 'SF Cluster Admin' privileges, and the ones that will allow only to query the info about your cluster.

> In addition to the cluster certificates, you can add client
>   certificates to perform management operations on a service fabric
>   cluster. You can add two kinds of client certificates - Admin or
>   Read-only. These then can be used to control access to the admin
>   operations and Query operations on the cluster. By default, the
>   cluster certificates are added to the allowed Admin certificates list.
>   you can specify any number of client certificates. Each
>   addition/deletion results in a configuration update to the service
>   fabric cluster